# Existence of extension of isometries on subspaces of $\ell_{p}(\mathbb N)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, isometry

Consider $\ell_{p}(\mathbb N)$ with $p\in\{1,\infty\}$.
Let $Y\subseteq\ell_{p}(\mathbb N)$ be a closed linear subspace and $\varphi\colon Y\rightarrow Y$ a (not necesserily surjective) isometry.

> Can this isometry be extended to an isometry, *i.e.*, $\overline{\varphi}:\ell_{p}(\mathbb N)\rightarrow\ell_{p}(\mathbb N)$ with $\overline{\varphi}\mid Y=\varphi$?